# Show hidden files in Finder but not on desktop with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, finder

I'd like to see the dot hidden files in the Finder but not on the Desktop, is that possible?
(`.localized` and `.DS_Store` on my desktop really annoy me.)
I'm using Snow Leopard (Mac OS X v10.6).

Comment: This question is more appropriate for SuperUser.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but useful to know: in Save/Open dialog boxes in applications, you can press Command-Shift-. to show/hide hidden files.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, no: the desktop **is** Finder.

But there is a reasonable workaround: you make a tiny AppleScript app that toggles AppleShowAllFiles for you and drag it to your Finder toolbar, making a button to run it.  See this article at [Macworld](http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/72863-mac-os-x-hints-weblog-show-all-files-in-the-finder/).

Answer (score 0):

I use [sterMachine](http://stermachine.en.softonic.com/mac)  and find it very useful. show hidden files is just one of the things that it does, and it doesn't show them on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you like a clean desktop, you there is an option in [Hyperspaces](https://hyperspacesapp.com) that hides all files on the desktop, yet you can still see them in Open File dialogs and regular Finder windows.

Comment: It does hide all the files on the desktop, not only the hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

You could just move them into a corner, under the dock, so that they exist on the desktop but you only see a few pixels of one of their corners.

Comment: except if you use the grid system. If the person asking this is OCD like I am, that's not an option.