# Open dot-file via GUI "open file" dialog?

Tags: macos, gui, dotfiles

Is there any way to open a file with a leading `.` in the filename using just the regular File > Open... dialog?

Comment: It not only displays "dot-files", but *any* hidden files (including those hidden with the `chflags hidden <filename>` command).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (Command-shift-.) will toggle hidden file visibility in open dialogs.

(Thanks, [Lyle](https://superuser.com/questions/140366/show-hidden-files-in-finder-but-not-on-desktop-with-mac-os-x/161100#161100)!)

Comment: Gah, beat me by 22 seconds!

Comment: Yeah, I found the answer while composing the question because different search terms occurred to me.  Sorry to be a tease.

Comment: Nah, it's fine. No worries :D